# How do I convert this stoi use in c++11 to atoi?

Tags: c++, c

I cant really update my C++ compiler right now, and would like to know how I can change `stoi` to `atoi` without getting a compiling error

```
    int getInput(int columns)
{
   // declare the variable to hold user input
   int userInput;
   string userValue;

   // prompt for the column number and read the column number
   cout << "Enter a column between 1 and " << columns << " to play in: ";
   cin >> userValue;

   // loop to check the input validation
   while (!validateUserInput(userValue) || (stoi(userValue) < 1) || (stoi(userValue) > columns))
   {
       // re-prompt the user for the input
       cout << "Enter a column between 1 and " << columns << " to play in: ";
       cin >> userValue;      
   }
   userInput = stoi(userValue);

   // return the input
   return userInput;
}
```

Comment: Please don't spam language tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, add `#include <cstdlib>` to your code to use `atoi` if you don't have that.

Then, replace `stoi(userValue)` with `atoi(userValue.c_str())`.